# Делаю анимацию с классом Thread, метод run наследника runnable почему-то вызывается один раз

Tags: java, многопоточность, анимация, intellij-idea, отладка

Пыталась сделать анимацию с помощью многопоточности, но сообщение из метода run наследника класса Runnable выводится только один раз, в картинке заметных изменений не наблюдается, хотя вроде бы запустила поток как в документации. Он закрывается или проблема в чём-то другом?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    public Window() {
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Panel pl = new  Panel(getWidth(), getHeight());
        add(pl);
        Thread t = new Thread(pl);
        t.start();
        pl.repaint();

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private int width, height;
    public double k;
    public Panel(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        k=0;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(250, 200, 250, 350);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillPolygon(new int[]{150, 400, 350, 200}, new int[]{350, 350, 450, 450}, 4);
        g.fillPolygon(new int[]{250, 350, 250}, new int[]{200, 280, 325}, 3);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        int[] xPoly = new int[width];
        for(int i=0; i<width; ++i)
        {
            xPoly[i]=i;
        }
        int[] yPoly = setSin();
        g.fillPolygon(xPoly, yPoly, width);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(width-100, -100, 200, 200);
if(true)
{


}


    }

    private int[] setSin()
    {
        int[] yPoly = new int[width];
        yPoly[0]=width;
        yPoly[width-1]=width;

        for(int i=1; i<width-1; ++i)
        {
            yPoly[i]=400-(int)(20*(Math.sin((double)(i)/40+k*20)));
        }

System.out.println("py")   ;
        return yPoly;
    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print("run");
            if(k==500)
                k=0;
            ++k;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Где тут многопоточность, если вы запускаете один поток?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поток выполняет метод run один раз и если метод run закончил выполнение, то поток заканчивает свою роботу. Это обычное поведение.

Если вам нужно чтоб поток продолжал работу и делал что-то полезное, то нужно в методе run сделать цикл.